# fluentd-elasticsearch unable to mount hostPath volume error

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, fluentd, daemonset

At my company the kubernetes cluster is managed by a team, we must provision a namespace and then create our resources. We cannot use features such as `hostPath` volumes and we cannot create new roles or namespaces, etc.

So looking at an example implementation of the `fluentd-elasticsearch` container as a `DaemonSet`, they all appear to be using hostPath volume mounting but I'm not sure why.

For example, I ran through this:
https://www.howtoforge.com/create-a-daemonset-in-kubernetes/

And created this:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: my-fluentd-elasticsearch-daemonset
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: fluentd-logging
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: fluentd-elasticsearch
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: fluentd-elasticsearch
    spec:
      tolerations:
      - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
        effect: NoSchedule
      containers:
      - name: fluentd-elasticsearch
        image: quay.io/fluentd_elasticsearch/fluentd:v2.5.2
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 200Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 200Mi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: varlog
          mountPath: /var/log
        - name: varlibdockercontainers
          mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
          readOnly: true
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - name: varlog
        hostPath:
          path: /var/log
      - name: varlibdockercontainers
        hostPath:
          path: /var/lib/docker/containers
```

But got this error:

```
Error creating: pods "fluentd-elasticsearch-" is forbidden: unable to validate against any pod 
security policy: [spec.volumes[0]: Invalid value: "hostPath": hostPath volumes are not allowed 
to be used spec.volumes[1]: Invalid value: "hostPath": hostPath volumes are not allowed to be 
used]
```

So I have a couple of questions:

1. Is fluentd mounting volumes then reading files in those volumes that get pushed out to elasticsearch?
2. Can I just remove the volume mounting or is that essential to it functioning?
3. Is fluentd using the kubernetes API at all?
4. Are there any non-daemonset containers which would just use the kubernetes API to get the pods then use log api to forward to a log db?

Comment: I have similar one at my company too, only get access to a namespace. But I can still create Persistence volume / claim, I guess you should also able to do that. Check with you k8s team. Info on k8s pv/pvc - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/

Comment: Yes I can do that, so is it just that it needs to write files somewhere? I was imagining it was trying to get access to the hosts logs based on docs is that not true?

Comment: Are you trying to monitor nodes using fluentd ? In that case, you may not be able to do it without having full access to the whole cluster and the host path. Your k8s admin team have to set it up. I have used fluentd in the past to aggregate logs from the application running inside pod.

Comment: No I just want to monitor my own pods, I can see the pods when I use the kube api and when I run `kubectl logs` command it shows me all the output correctly, I basically just want something that does that but streams it out to a database. I don't understand why all these solutions seem to need volume mounting to the node and full daemon sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is fluentd mounting volumes then reading files in those volumes that get pushed out to elasticsearch?

Docker is storing logs on the node's disk. Fluentd needs to acces this log files somehow; this is why its running as daemonset, you need it to run on every node with hostpath to access log files.

> Can I just remove the volume mounting or is that essential to it functioning?

No, you can't "just remove" volume mounting (hostpath) because fluentd will loose access to the log files that docker keeps on nodes.

> Is fluentd using the kubernetes API at all?

There is no straightforward answer to this question. There are plugins I have found that can access k8s metadata using k8s api but I haven't found any plugin that would use k8s api to pull logs.

> Are there any non-daemonset containers which would just use the kubernetes API to get the pods then use log api to forward to a log db?

Some similar to this is describled in k8s documentation: [sidecar container with a logging agent](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#sidecar-container-with-a-logging-agent)

So yes, you could possibly deploy fluentd as a sidecar to gather and forward logs to the db. Check the docs for more details.

Comment: Unfortunately I still don't have hostPath permissions even in the same pod.

I suppose I could have my application log to a file which is volume mounted to a shared persistent volume... What I've been looking for is something that uses the kubernetes pod/log api since I do have permissions for that and it appears to have everything.

Comment: Or actually... looking at that link I see that this is what the sidecar is doing but without the persistent storage. I think this took way too long for me to grok. Thanks.